# ATtiny V-USB with 115200bps? DIP only

Tags: usb, uart, attiny

I know there are several solutions for V-USB using only DIP Parts (especially the ATtiny) like

IgorPlug

- http://obdev.at/products/vusb/easylogger.html
- http://cesko.host.sk/IgorPlugUSB/IgorPlug-USB%20%28AVR%29_eng.htm
- http://www.recursion.jp/avrcdc/cdc-232.html

But they are limited to 38400bps!

- Why?
- Are there other solutions only using DIP packaged parts for easy soldering?

Comment: Don't fear surface mount soldering. It's probably much easier than you think. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4678/what-tools-equipments-and-techniques-do-you-use-to-solder-microminiature-smd-par

Comment: I don't doubt that! But it's part of a series of projects for beginners and therefore we want to stick to DIP packaged parts.

Comment: Note that there is also [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php), though I not sure whether or not it has the same speed limits.

Comment: If it's for absolute beginners, 38kbit should be plenty. When they want more speed, they can graduate to the slightly more complex setups -- eg using USB AVR's with built in USB hardware. I believe LUFA has a theoretical limit of around 8000kbit via CDC, but that's only if you're just sending a constant stream of data from RAM. It requires USB AVR though, I don't think any come in DIP.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right that 38kbit is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because software USB on AVR can only be 1.0 which is 1mbit max. If we subtract overheads on USB protocol and processing, even 384kbit looks awesome. If you need more - take specialized chip from FTDI for example.

SOIC soldering is not hard, and possible without fancy equipment.
If you want to prototype with SOIC you can solder tiny wires to leads.

Comment: As mentioned above the circuit is intended for beginners and we would like to stick to DIP packaged parts.

Comment: FTDI chips are deadly simple. You just solder it and it works fine.  No debugging.

Comment: Also, FTDI chips are available pre-soldered to DIP modules for a reasonable price.